# Select integer as bit & state table using postgresql

Tags: postgresql

How can I select an integer as a table of bit# & state? For example if my int was 13 I would like to see this output.

```
bit# | state
 0   |   1
 1   |   0
 2   |   1
 3   |   1
 4   |   0
 5   |   0
 ..  |   ..
```

Comment: When asking a question, you should show that you tried to solve the problem yourself and epxlain what didn't work. I can't see any research effort in your question. 
Anyways - what you need are bitwise logical operators, here's an example for your number 13:
`select 
13 & 1 as bit_0, 
13 & 2 as bit_1, 
13 & 4 as bit_2, 
13 & 8 as bit_3, 
13 & 16 as bit_4, 
13 & 32 as bit_5, 
13 & 64 as bit_6,
13 & 128 as bit_7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operations on bits are straightforward in Postgres with [Bit String Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-bit.html). You can easily convert an integer to a bit string, e.g.:

```sql
select 13::bit(8);
   bit
----------
 00001101
(1 row)
```

You need to cast the bit string value to text array and unnest it to get the results in the form of a table:

```sql
select 8- ord as bit, state
from unnest(string_to_array(13::bit(8)::text, null)) with ordinality as u(state, ord)
order by 1
```

The required number of bits must be set a priori. Replace 8 with the given number in the above query. In Postgres 14+ you can use `string_to_table()` instead of `unnest(string_to_array()).`

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8a0d48b1be1c4dcb6cdec4e1878c560c)